# Prove every finite lattice has a greatest element - without induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders

I have to prove that every finite lattice (L, ≤) has a greatest element. I have seen a lot of proofs proving this by using induction, however, I have to prove it without induction since our institution says that in an induction proof we can't be sure that we're still dealing with a lattice in the hypothesis of induction part.

So I guess a constructive proof would be a solution. Can anyone help me with this or show me an example of how it could possibly be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, for one thing, your institution is wrong--there are certainly valid proofs of this statement by induction (you just have to prove a slightly different statement by induction, rather than literally directly proving the statement by induction on $|L|$).  And really, it is very difficult to imagine any proof that doesn't use induction in some form.

Comment: Well, to begin, suppose $L = \{x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$. What do you think the greatest element looks like in terms of the elements, $\vee$ and $\wedge$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already proved (e.g. by induction) that every (nonempty) finite partially ordered set has a *maximal* element, then you can argue as follows to show that a finite lattice $(L,\le)$ has a greatest element.

Let $a$ be a maximal element of $L;$ I claim that $a$ is the greatest element of $L.$ Consider any element $x\in L;$ I have to show that $x\le a.$ We know that $a\le x\vee a,$ but $a\not\lt x\vee a$ because $a$ is maximal, so $a=x\vee a$ and $x\le x\vee a=a.$

Answer (score 1):

You can still prove it by induction, you just have to be careful about what it is you are proving by induction.  What you want to prove by induction on $n$ is that if $(L,\leq)$ is a lattice and $A\subseteq L$ is a subset with $n$ elements, then there is an element $x\in L$ such that $x\geq a$ for all $a\in A$.  Given a finite lattice $(L,\leq)$, you can then apply this statement with $n=|L|$ and $A=L$ to get that $L$ has a greatest element.  Since you do not assume that $A$ is a lattice but merely that it is a subset of a lattice (and your upper bound $x$ might be in $L\setminus A$), you avoid the difficulty you mentioned.